# Finding goal in DepthFirstSearch

Tags: java, stack, graph-algorithm, path-finding, depth-first-search

I just wondering where to put this code

```
if(node == goal){
            System.out.print("Found path: ");
            for(int n : stack){
                System.out.print(n + " ");
            }
        }
```

in this method:

```
public void performRecursiveDFS(Graph G, int node, int goal) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(node);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        node = stack.pop();
         if (!visited[node]) {
            visited[node] = true;
            for (int w : G.adjList(node)) {
                stack.push(w);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the reason is, I want to print the path from the start node to the goal node. For example like this, `Found path: 0 1 2 3 4 7`. I tried putting it after `node = stack.pop()` but it showed me something like this `Found path: 3`. Any reason/suggestion? Is there something wrong with my code? If so, please direct me in detail. Questions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented part of the DFS that keep track of visited nodes and you can extend it to know source path also that link to next node

Full DFS implementation will look something like below that will handle paths request also

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Deque;


public class DirectedDFS {

    private final Digraph g;
    private final int source;

    private boolean[] marked;
    private int[] edgeFrom;

    public DirectedDFS(Digraph g, int source) {
        this.g = g;
        this.source = source;
        init(g);
        dfs(g, source);
    }

    private void init(Digraph g) {
        this.marked = new boolean[g.V()];
        this.edgeFrom = new int[g.V()];
        Arrays.fill(edgeFrom, -1);
    }

    private void dfs(Digraph g, int source) {

        marked[source] = true;
        for (int vertex : g.adj(source)) {
            if (!marked[vertex]) {
                edgeFrom[vertex] = source;
                dfs(g, vertex);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hasPath(int v) {
        return marked[v];
    }

    public Iterable<Integer> path(int v) {
        if (hasPath(v)) {
            final Deque<Integer> paths = new ArrayDeque<>();
            int vertex = v;
            paths.push(v);
            while ((vertex = edgeFrom[vertex]) != -1) {
                paths.push(vertex);
            }
            return paths;
        }
        return (Iterable<Integer>) Collections.emptyIterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm currently working with undirected graph where I have a text file contains a pair of numbers (nodes) to show connections between two nodes. Is this the same with directed graph?

Comment: Yes algo remains same for both type of graph.

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thanks. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I have tried what you said and it works. Thanks for that. Unfortunately, the problem in my paths are not complete. For example, my goal is to get to 1 from 0 and the path like this "-->0 -->3 -->3 -->0 -->5 -->4 -->5 -->7 -->7 -->8 -->9" but I have 0 -  11 vertex. Do you know why this is happening? If this is another question then I can post another question related to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes i think you should post another question on this

Answer (score 0):

The stack is currently storing nodes to check next not nodes that have already been checked to get to the current point.

To get the path taken you will need to create a list and add each node that is checked to that list.

Once you get a node you can check if that node is the goal node then you can print out the list

Answer (score 0):

You currently aren't storing the path to the current node so you can't print it. A fairly easy way to achieve this is to use a map to plot the path back to the origin. This can replace your use of the `visited` array.

Here's how it would look:

```
public void performRecursiveDFS(Graph G, int start, int goal) {
    Stack<Integer> remaining = new Stack<Integer>();
    remaining.push(start);
    Map<Integer, Integer> previous = new HashMap<>();
    while (!remaining .isEmpty()) {
        int current = remaining.pop();
        if (current == goal) {
            Deque<Integer> path = new LinkedList<>();
            path.addFirst(current);
            while (previous.containsKey(path.peek())
                path.addFirst(previous.get(path.peek()));
            // print path
        } else if (!previous.containsKey(current)) {
            for (int w : G.adjList(current)) {
                previous.put(w, current);
                remaining.push(w);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For simplicity, is Map necessary? I haven't worked with it before.

Comment: @MCMadMoefat no it's not necessary - you can create a list of the path as you go.

Comment: I tried testing your code to understand how it works. Somehow, it doesn't print the path when I put System.out.print method under "//print path" comment. I don't know if I did was wrong.